# Unity Dictionary with Action[]

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, action, speech-recognition

I want to make a speech recognition in Unity with VS 2019 and I came across a dictionary with strings and actions, like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, Action[]> actions = new Dictionary<string, Action[]>();
```

I use a list of actions because I want to be more complex than recognizing simple words. Like: **turn right** or **change color to green**.

But when I want to add an element to this dictionary:

```
actions.Add("up", Up); // first line in example
```

where Up is a function:

```
private void Up()
    {
        posY += speed; 
    }
```

it gives me the error "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action[]'" under Up (at the line where i commented first line in example). But if my dictionary is not with Action[] but with Action (not array) it works just fine.

Firstly, how can I solve this problem and get rid of that error? And secondly, is there a better way for advanced speech recognition? I want to recognize a phrase like **turn right and change color to green**.

Comment: `actions.Add("up", new Action[] { Up });`

Comment: well `Action` != `Action[]`

Comment: Yeah, I know that Action != Action[] because the second one it's an array. But I'm not that advanced at C# (my main language is C++) and I didn't know how to create an Action list from a simple Action. Thanks, it works just great. But do you have any suggestions for advance speech recognition? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary holds an array of Actions.

```
actions.Add("up", new Action[] { Up });
```